# Table of Contents adjust sections to a set maximum width and the page number on very right

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to figure out a way to adjust my ToC so that long titles do not come too close to the page number. There should be a clear space between them. How is this best accomplished?

So far, the ToC looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look somewhat like this:

[image]

This is probably best achieve with **titletoc**, no? Or with adjusting **\titlecontents{section}**? I've been trying for some time now but nothing seems to work.

EDIT: I used tocrmarg and it solved my problem:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.5em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{8.5em}
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{0em}%
  {\dimexpr\baselineskip+2.5ex\relax}%
  {\dimexpr\baselineskip\relax}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\leftskip=2.5em}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

I'm still trying to find a way to remove the section number right before the section title (1 and 2). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could adjust `\@tocrmarg`, but without minimal working example, it is hard to say, whether or not it would help.

Comment: Thank you, tocrmarg worked fine. I put the changes in my edited post.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please add an answer, but do not change the question to also answer it.